# How to process multiple input

Tags: python, input

I need some help with the coding.

```
data1 = float(raw_input('Enter Value: '))
data2 = float(raw_input('Enter Another Value: '))
finaldata = data1 + data2
print ("Your value is %s" %(finaldata))
```

This is the simple code I write and every time I put a value in`data1`, `data2` will also automatically use `data1` value. Making it unable to enter value in `data2` prompt.

`data1, data2 = input('Enter Value: ')` is one of the solution I know but is there any other solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: with the above code, I can enter e.g., '5.3' fine, and then '2.2', and then it'll print `Your value is 7.5`.

Comment: I dont understand what you're asking. Do you want your code to store the same value in separate variables or different? If the latter your code should work fine.

Comment: Whenever I enter e.g '5.3', it will skip to print and give the final value of '10.6'. So I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: Show us your print screen, it's hard to understand what is happening.

Comment: I am currently using http://repl.it/, a web based browser that can write python code online. So I don't know if that is the factor that give rise to this problem.

Comment: It's not, I've tried it and i cannot reproduce.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/usermedia.php?uo=fNkd6hpTbcNKaY3Fg9RbmIh4l5k2TGxc#.U2n0pU1WESk

Comment: this is the picture link.

Comment: That website works fine for me. It must be an issue on your end. Try a different browser/interpreter or clear browsing data see if that helps.